# symfony access_control not working

Tags: symfony, routes, access-control

My acces_control insisde the security.yml doesn't work. I already cleared the cache without any result :)

As I read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html), I could found anything wrong.... NOrmally, only ROLE_ADMIN should have access to the path /user/. The role is correct, I tested it with

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
```

inside Twig.

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: pbkdf2

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CUSTOMER_REVISION: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_CUSTOMER_MANAGER:  [ROLE_CUSTOMER_REVISION, ROLE_IOS]
    ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN:    ROLE_CUSTOMER_MANAGER
    ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN]

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
         pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
         security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /{locale}/
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

AM I doing something wrong which I dont see?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to sort acces_control clauses from the most specific to the most general:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

This is because the route `/admin` is matched by `^/` pattern too, so the restrictive pattern `^/admin/` must be placed before.

Comment: hi and thanx for this quick feedback. I sorted it the way you showed up. But I have still access. I guess, using "locale" before doesn't mater as I use the ^ isn't it?

Roles  [ROLE_CUSTOMER_MANAGER, ROLE_USER]

Comment: I never used locale in URLs with Symfony, but maybe you have to change all your patterns this way : ^/[a-z]{2}/admin/

Comment: It's weird cause in my twig template, it works perfect. So I guess it's not a problem with the role itself.